# React Native - The selected item is always in the middle of the Flatlist

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to make sure that the selected item is always in the middle of the flatlist. The middle item is selected. The style of the chosen one is different than the others.

```
 <FlatList data={items}
                                      style={styles.listStyle}
                                      ref={(ref) => {
                                          this.flatListRef = ref;
                                      }}
                                      snapToAlignment={'center'}
                                      horizontal

                                      onPress={this.onPressButton}
                                      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                                          <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
                                                                    onPress={this.onPressButton}>
                                              <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                                                  <View   style={styles.containerView}>
                                                      <View
                                                          style={[styles.circlesBack, (this.state.selectedId === index) ? styles.circles : styles.circlesBack]}>
                                                          {this.state.selectedId === index ?
                                                              <FontAwesome size={24} name={item.icon} color="white"/> :
                                                              <FontAwesome size={24} name={item.icon} color="#BEBEBE"/>}
                                                      </View>
                                                      {this.state.selectedId === index ? <Text
                                                              style={[styles.itemText, (this.state.selectedId === index) ? styles.itemText : styles.itemTextBack]}>{item.title}</Text> :
                                                          <Text> </Text>}

                                                  </View>
                                              </View>
                                          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                      )}
                                      keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
```

this is what it looks like now
[image]

it should look like this
[image]

How to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Is this answer what you want ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43512934/13107433

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately, that didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use like this:

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 30, viewPosition:0.5})
```

Valid params keys are:

'animated' (boolean) - Whether the list should do an animation while scrolling. Defaults to true.

'viewPosition' (number) - A value of 0 places the item specified by index at the top, 1 at the bottom, and 0.5 centered in the middle.

Here is someone's code for [example](https://snack.expo.io/@s2gt05/flatlist-scrolltoindex-practical-example.-), you can instead the line

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 30,viewPosition:0.5});
```

of

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: randomIndex});
```

then you can see it works(at right choose android or ios to run will be better)

[docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend)

But the several begins item seems can't go to middle because of there are no data before. Or you can use [react-native-infinite-looping-scroll](https://github.com/prateek3255/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll) to let other data at bottom connect back to first. Maybe can achieve this problem.